Is subscripting [] or a conditional ?: syntactically an operator?
The most recent publicly available C++ Standard draft specifies the following syntactically as an operator or punctuator (Each operator-or-punctuator is converted to a single token):
https://eel.is/c++draft/lex.operators
Section 7.6.1.2 of the Standard draft defines the meaning of a subscript expression. There are several occurences of the phrase "subscript operator", e.g.

A subscript expression is a postfix expression followed by square brackets containing a possibly empty, comma-separated list of initializer-clauses that constitute the arguments to the subscript operator.


With the built-in subscript operator, an expression-list shall be present, consisting of a single assignment-expression.


This is true even if the subscript operator is used in the following common idiom: &x[0].

Section 7.6.16 defines the meaning of a conditional expression. The section title includes the phrase "Conditional operator", but except for the title there is no other occurence of the phrase "conditional operator" in the definition of the meaning.
So according to section 5.12, subscripting [] or a conditional ?: is syntactically not an operator.
Question: Why does the Standard include phrases such as "subscript operator" or "conditional operator", but does not define what a "subscript operator" or "conditional operator" is?

[lex.operators] provides a list of all the operators including [ etc so yes it is syntactically an operator. The standard explains what a Subscript "expression" means which is how it explains all operators  use. That is, [lex.operators] already mentions [ etc so and the standard already describes the meaning of subscript expression so I don't think there is any need of adding any more definition of subscript "operator" as it won't make sense.

"Why does the Standard include phrases such as "subscript operator" or "conditional operator", but does not define what a "subscript operator" or "conditional operator" is?..." The standard describes only "expressions" corresponding to the operators. For example, the "comma operator" and the "function call operator" etc all are defined this way. So this isn't specific to just subscript or conditional operators.

Also, the standard uses the terms "square brackets" and "parentheses" while defining the expressions corresponding to the operators which I think is more sensible and clear than the terms "subscript operator" and "function call operator". They could just say/define "subscript operator means square brackets..." but just using square brackets and parentheses is more universal.

subscript operator and conditional operator

[over.sub] "...A subscripting operator function is a..."

@RichardCritten That is different. They're talking about a non-static "member function" there in [over.sub].

@NathanOliver I saw that as well but that again is only describing "subscript expression" not "subscript operator". Though I think defining the expression's behavior is the right way(or intended way) to define/mean the operator as done will all other operators as well.

https://cplusplus.github.io/CWG/issues/189.html? (From https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75824669/which-elements-of-operator-or-punctuator-are-punctuators#comment133751252_75824669)

@user12002570 A lot of C++ people use the term "function call operator", but actually there is no "function call operator". C++ has function calls, and the recent standard does not use the term "function call operator" in the definition of the meaning of function calls (https://eel.is/c++draft/expr.call). In the context of operator overloading, there is the term "function call operator function".

@j.j. There is the term "function call operator" in c++. The c++ standard uses that term itself more than 20 times.

@user12002570 As I already said, the standard uses this term only in the context of operator overloading, but there is no built-in "function call operator". See here https://eel.is/c++draft/over.oper. Otherwise, show me a reference where the standard mentions "function call operator" outside the operator overloading context.

@j.j. expr.mptr.oper explicitly refers to "function call operator" ().

@user12002570 You are right. However, they do not use "function call operator" here: https://eel.is/c++draft/expr.call

@j.j. Yes, this seems to be something to be fixed in the standard. I'll add an answer once/if it gets fixed.

I've rolled back your latest edit as it invalidates the answer that was already given. If you want to ask something different, ask a new question. You can cross-reference to this question if you think it is necessary.

It does describe what those operators are. The operator in a given expression is "the expression operator".
The section headed "7.6.1.2 Subscripting [expr.sub]" defines the subscripting operator, i.e. the operator in the production rule

postfix-expression [ expression-listopt ]

The section headed "7.6.16 Conditional operator [expr.cond]" defines the conditional operator, i.e. the operator in the production rule

logical-or-expression ? expression : assignment-expression



Question: Why does the Standard include phrases such as "subscript operator" or "conditional operator", but does not define what a "subscript operator" or "conditional operator" is?

You could ask the same question about most of the symbolic operators. There isn't a definition of "the prefix increment operator", there is just a grammar rule for

++cast-expression

Ditto "the addition operator"

additive-expression + multiplicative-expression


OP already know this. They already said in their post "Section 7.6.1.2 of the Standard draft defines the meaning of a subscript expression..." This is answering the question by repeating the question as answer .

@user12002570 What OP is missing is in my opening paragraph: "The operator in a given expression is the expression operator."

Again that is cyclic. There is no "expression operator" defined by the standard. It is just jumbling words here and there.

@user12002570 expression is a placeholder, e.g. "The operator in the conditional expression is the conditional operator". That's the ordinary English meaning of operator.

There is a problem with that english definition. In particular, it doesn't tell you which operator it is talking about when there are multiple operators involved in the expression like in conditional expression. That is the point of the question, that the standard doesn't actually define the term and we can't assume that the programmatic term is equivalent to the normal english term.

@user12002570 it is the combination ? and : that are the conditional operator, neither one on their own is.

Yes, but that english definition doesn't tell us that. A proper definition would need to tell us the order like ?: not :? etc and then how all operators appearing are combined etc. The point I am making is that the term has separate/particular programmatic meaning.

@user12002570 helpfully the C++ standard does define that it's ?:, furthermore it is specifically logical-or-expression ? expression : assignment-expression

No, standard defines them as expressions, although title of section for ?: is "conditional operator". But conditional operator is NOT ?:. It's either an expression convertible to bool

logical-or-expression

or

logical-or-expression ? expression : assignment-expression

because logical-or-expression is equal to logical-or-expression ? true : false. why it is called "operator" like other overload-enabled expression. This is outside of standard's scope, but my own reasoning is  that it's because we can overload operator bool(), effectively altering behaviour of version (1).
Subscripting is defined as one of "postfix expressions" [expr.compound] [expr.post]. Postifix de\increments, typeid, cast expressions and access to class memebrs are postfix expressions.
Actually there are 3 levels on which these are defined: lexic, syntactic and semantic. On lexic level standard defines operator-or-punctuator term, which covers them all, even if they consist of several separate lexems. operator-or-punctuator is one of:
{   }    [    ]   (    )   <:  :>  <%   %>  ;    :    ...   ?   :: 
.   .*  ->   ->*  ~    !   +-   *  /    %   ^    &    |     =   +=  
-=  *=  /=   %=   ^=   &=  |=  ==  !=   <   >   <=   >=   <=>   &&  
||  <<  >>   <<=  >>=  ++  --  ,  

and  or  xor  not  bitand  bitor compl  and_eq  or_eq  xor_eq  not_eq

These are lexem, i.e. elements of syntax constructs. Your "conditional operator" consists of two lexems - ? and : which must separate three distinct expressions.
Some of them are both punctuators and parts of an expression, e.g. () (operator of function call) is semantically an operator, while parenthesis used in arithmetic expressions are punctuation just like commas between function's arguments. In a variable declaration these are taking punctuation role:
// no operators here, it's a declaration of array
int (*fptr_array [5]) (int, int[]) = {};

In fact, Standard defines expressions and their structure and rules, not operators. Term operator usually appears where we can define them for class-types as "special " functions. On that level a cast-expression, some expression int(var) where id-expression var got class-type T can result in a call to a user-defined operator T::operator int().
On other hand, these highly formal definitions are rather confusing and lengthy for casual use, so colliquially we call distinct elements of expressions "operators" e.g. what we usually call "new operator" is actually a new-expression.
P.S. There are two lexems called operators in C and C++ which noone considers operators (and not everyone remembers of their existence) - preprocessor operators # and ## (%: and %:%:).

"Term operator appears where we can define them for class-types as "special " functions..." Not necessarily true, we do have expr.mptr.oper that explicitly refers to "function call operator" ().

@user12002570: That example supports the claim rather than disproving it.  See operator()(), the user-overload for a function call operator.  It's what makes a "function object" an invocable, like a raw function.

@user12002570 yes, because we can define it for class-types, which leads to them behave  like functions in an expression. Same with pointer-to-member operators and ->. But we can't redefine ..

@BenVoigt but it's a good comment, I forgot to offer them as an example.
